# Conditional Filter One Column and Update Same Row in New Column

Tags: r

Would it be possible to do a conditional filter in one column and subsequently update another column but of the same row position?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Harry", "Charles"), Amount = c(30, -30, 49), Budget = c(51, 53, 55))

     name Amount Budget
1     Tom     30     51
2   Harry    -30     53
3 Charles     49     55
```

For instance, I'm trying to filter out all values that are below 0 under the amount column, and update the budget column (replace the existing value) for Harry.

```
     name Amount Budget
1     Tom     30     51
2   Harry           -30
3 Charles     49     55
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. First, I create the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Harry", "Charles"), 
                 Amount = c(30, -30, 49), 
                 Budget = c(51, 53, 55))
```

Next, I set `Budget` to `Amount` if `Amount` is less than zero, then set `Amount` to `NA` if `Amount` is less than zero.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Budget = ifelse(Amount < 0, Amount, Budget),
         Amount = ifelse(Amount < 0, NA, Amount))
```

giving,

```
#      name Amount Budget
# 1     Tom     30     51
# 2   Harry     NA    -30
# 3 Charles     49     55
```

Of course, you could set `Amount` to zero rather than `NA`, if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
#Find out indices where Amount is less than 0
inds <- df$Amount < 0

#Replace the corresponding Budget value by Amount value
df$Budget[inds] <- df$Amount[inds]

#Change the Amount to 0
df$Amount[inds] <- 0 #Replacing it with 0 since it's a numeric column

df

#     name Amount Budget
#1     Tom     30     51
#2   Harry      0    -30
#3 Charles     49     55
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work for large dataframes though, would it be possible to tweak it ?

Comment: @Amanda not sure what you mean by `doesn't seem to work`. Can you explain what is not working? Do you get any error? It would be difficult to tweak it without knowing exactly where it fails since it works on your example dataframe.

Comment: No idea why, but the dplyr solution seems to work for my dataframe instead! I think it could be the sheer size of large dataframes though.